# Irreducible polynomial with root implies least degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $\alpha$ be an element of an extension field $K$ of the field $F$ that is algebraic over $F$. Then, if $f$ is an irreducible element of $F[x]$, and $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $f$ is the monic polynomial of lowest degree in $F[x]$ that has $\alpha$ as a root.

How do I show that such irreducible polynomial is unique? Suppose that there are two irreducible polynomials $f,g$ satisfying $f(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\alpha)=0$. Then by division algorithm, by dividing $f$ by $g$, say, I find a polynomial $r$ with less degree than both $f$ with $\alpha$ as a root. Now I divide say the quotient by $r$, and continue. Then, by successive division remainders I get in each step, I get either constant reminder or 0 remainder. Constant remainder means that $\alpha$ not root of the last remainder, but that means that $\alpha$ not root of $f$, last remainder zero means $f$ reducible.

Am I correct above?

Comment: For uniqueness: suppose that there are two monic polynomial $f,g$ of lowest degree, then $f-g$ has lower degree and $\alpha$ is a root of $f-g$

Comment: This is called the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ and a very important concept.

Comment: @dcolazin, is my approach correct for proving 'irreducible + $\alpha$ is a root implies polynomial with lowest degree with $\alpha$ as a root'?

Comment: @Silent yes, but I would write it faster: let $g$ the one with lowest degree, $f$ irreducible, then $f(x) = q(x)g(x) + r(x)$ with $r \neq 0$ and $\deg r < \deg g$, but $0 = f(\alpha) = q(\alpha)g(\alpha) + r(\alpha) = r(\alpha)$, so $\alpha$ is a root of $r$, which is absurd